# Linux- javac Command Not Found

Tags: java, linux

I use puTTy to connect to a remote server running Linux. When I run

```
abc@myName((/home/myName)$java -version
```

I get the following

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Then I used `readlink -f $(which java)` to find the location of the java command and I got the location as `/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java`.

Now I navigated to this location and listed the files

```
abc@myName(/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin)$ls
appletviewer  idlj       javac           javap         jconsole  jinfo    jps         jstat      native2ascii  rmic         serialver   wsgen
apt           jar        javadoc         java-rmi.cgi  jcontrol  jmap     jrunscript  jstatd     orbd          rmid         servertool  wsimport
ControlPanel  jarsigner  javafxpackager  javaws        jdb       jmc      jsadebugd   jvisualvm  pack200       rmiregistry  tnameserv   xjc
extcheck      java       javah           jcmd          jhat      jmc.ini  jstack      keytool    policytool    schemagen    unpack200
```

Then I tried the following

```
abc@myName(/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin)$javac
```

And got

```
-bash: javac: command not found
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: What does your $PATH look like

Comment: Is `/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin` in your `PATH`?

Comment: What happens if you use the full path? (`/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac`)

Comment: @cup @0x5453 No, the location isn't present in `PATH` but I did navigate to that location and then tried `javac`

Comment: Refer to here https://askubuntu.com/questions/430434/replace-openjdk-with-oracle-jdk-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JDK folder you specified is not in your PATH. The current directory is not in your PATH either. Option 1.

```
cd /opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin
./javac
```

That is using the local path.

Option 2.

```
/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac
```

That is using the full path.

Option 3.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin
javac
```

That is adding the folder to your PATH.

Answer (score 3):

In terminal, type the command `javac -version`

Does it yield the following message?

> ```
> The command «javac» was not found, but it can be installed with: 
>
> apt install default-jdk            
> apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless
> apt install ecj                    
> apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
> ```

If so, use `apt install default-jdk` and javac will be working again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a $PATH issue. $PATH is an environment variable that contains a list of directories to search when looking for an executable

Try to exceute this command:

export PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:$PATH